# When is correct to use the is operator in delphi?

Tags: delphi

How can I test that a not nil TObject does not hold an object of a specific class in the case below?

```
procedure TForm7.testme;
var
    mystring: string;
    obj: TObject;
begin
    mystring := 'asd';
    obj := TObject(mystring);

    if assigned(obj) then
        if obj is TestClass then // --> this is failing
        // ...
end;
```

Comment: You may come from another language, where strings are objects. In Delphi, a string is **not** an object, so you shouldn't cast it to one.

Comment: Oh, and `is` is not a "command", it is an operator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
obj := TObject(mystring);
```

This is the mistake. A `TObject` can hold a valid object, or `nil`. Anything else leads to undefined behaviour. Which means that `is`, or indeed anything else, cannot be expected to behave in any meaningful way.

The implementation of any method operating on an object reference relies implicitly on the reference actually being an object. For something like `is` the implementation looks up the class of the instance, which depends on the memory being laid out as an object. A string does not fit the bill.

The `is` operator can tell you information about the type of an object. It is illegal to pass something that is not an object to it, other than the special value `nil`.

The solution is to stop putting invalid data into your object reference.

Comment: Just curious, if type casting a string to a TObject is a mistake, why does the compiler not pick this up? Is this a bug for Embarcadero?

Comment: @Fero This is an unchecked cast. You are telling the compiler that you know better than it, and that it must suppress any type mismatch errors. As a general rule, unchecked casts are best avoided unless absolutely necessary.